# EntityNotFoundException in Spring Boot when calling service from controller after deployment to external Tomcat

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, spring-data-jpa

I have been developing a Spring Boot application (2.x series) using the embedded Tomcat server locally. Everything works fine in my local environment, but when I deploy the application to an external Tomcat server, I'm facing an issue with APIs that retrieve entities.

Locally, all my APIs, including those fetching entities, work perfectly. However, after deployment, the APIs that involve a service layer calling the repository layer start throwing *EntityNotFoundException*. Interestingly, when I bypass the service layer and call the repository directly from the controller, there are no errors, and the APIs work as expected.

## **Issue Detail**

**Environment**: Spring Boot 2.x, external Tomcat server.
**Behavior**: When calling a repository method through a service from the controller, it results in *EntityNotFoundException*.
**Observation**: Direct repository method calls from the controller (bypassing the service) work without any errors.

## **Non-Working Code Example**:

**Controller**:

```java
@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@RequestMapping("/api/admin")
public class SponsorController {

    private final SponsorService sponsorService;

    @GetMapping("/v1/sponsors")
    public ResponseEntity<ApiResponse<List<SponsorResponse>>> getSponsors() {
        List<SponsorResponse> result = sponsorService.findSponsors();
        ApiResponse<List<SponsorResponse>> response = ApiResponse.success(result);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(response);
    }

    @GetMapping("/v1/sponsors/{sponsorId}")
    public ResponseEntity<ApiResponse<SponsorResponse>> getSponsor(@PathVariable final Long sponsorId) {
        SponsorResponse result = sponsorService.findSponsor(sponsorId);
        ApiResponse<SponsorResponse> response = ApiResponse.success(result);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(response);
    }
}
```

**Service**:

```java
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SponsorService {

    private final SponsorRepository sponsorRepository;

    public List<SponsorResponse> findSponsors() {
        List<Sponsor> sponsors = sponsorRepository.findAll();
        return SponsorResponse.listOf(sponsors);
    }

    public SponsorResponse findSponsor(long sponsorId) {
        return sponsorRepository.findById(sponsorId).map(
            SponsorResponse::of
        ).orElseThrow(
            () -> new EntityNotFoundException(ErrorCode.ENTITY_NOT_FOUND)
        );
    }
}
```

## **Working Code Example (Direct Repository Access)**:

**Controller**:

```java
@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@RequestMapping("/api/admin")
public class SponsorController {

    private final SponsorRepository sponsorRepository;

    @GetMapping("/v1/sponsors")
    public ResponseEntity<ApiResponse<List<SponsorResponse>>> testSponsors() {
        List<Sponsor> all = sponsorRepository.findAll();
        List<SponsorResponse> sponsorResponses = SponsorResponse.listOf(all);
        ApiResponse<List<SponsorResponse>> response = ApiResponse.success(sponsorResponses);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(response);
    }

    @GetMapping("/v1/sponsors/{sponsorId}")
    public ResponseEntity<ApiResponse<SponsorResponse>> testSponsor(@PathVariable("sponsorId") Long sponsorId) {
        Sponsor sponsor = sponsorRepository.findById(sponsorId).orElseThrow(
            () -> new EntityNotFoundException(ErrorCode.ENTITY_NOT_FOUND)
        );
        SponsorResponse response = SponsorResponse.of(sponsor);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(ApiResponse.success(response));
    }
}
```

Does anyone have insights into why bypassing the service layer solves the issue after deployment? Could there be a misconfiguration or an environmental difference between local and server setups affecting the transactional behavior or proxy mechanism of the service layer? Any suggestions for debugging or fixing this issue would be greatly appreciated.

I tried to see if it was an issue with @Transactional

Comment: As a result of testing, there is no problem with this code.
It is difficult to identify the specific problem with the information you provided.
However, to identify the problem, we recommend debugging the service logic through logging using @Slf4j.
Check whether the parameters are properly passed to the service layer.